# Add multiple README on GitHub repo

Tags: github, multilingual, readme

Is it possible to add multiple README on a git repository? To write a french and a english file for example (`README.fr.md`, `README.en.md`).

(Of course, I know it's possible but it's not recognized by GitHub as a README.)

Comment: What's the end result you want to achieve with this? GitHub will still parse the Markdown and render it properly, if that's your concern.

Comment: It seems like it would be easy to just try this and see what happens...

Comment: @Stijn I want the visitor to be able to change easily between files, but on the main repo page.

Comment: @user247702 he wants to see different file say readme1.md or readme2.md files, to just like how REAMME.md file looks at bootom after scroll repo page

Comment: Do you mean multiple markdowns as in it shows tabs for it ? Like for [this](https://github.com/jdx/mise/) repository ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can add, but the default name of the base file should be `README.md`, and later, add the URLs of different languages on the top of the `README.md` file so that users can switch to other languages.

Also, make sure that you add the language switch option in each of the README file so that user can switch the language back to the default which is English(I assume)

Comment: Good idea! It's not exactly what I want, but it's okay. Thanks!

Comment: I know that's not what you're looking for but as of now there's no option for multiple languages either.

Comment: Do you just put the url or add any markdown as well?

Comment: Is this what you meant?
https://github.com/jonatasemidio/multilanguage-readme-pattern

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. This is possible! Just add READMEs in other languages following thr `W3C` language conventions.

- If for instance your repo supports also french, you would create a `README-fr.md` file, `README-es` for Spanish, etc..
- Then you just add reference to other languages in your main `REAMDE`

You can check this [ressource](https://github.com/jonatasemidio/multilanguage-readme-pattern) for more hints